# Is my ESTA still valid though I've mislaid it?

Tags: usa, esta, uk-citizens

I have mislaid my esta, I want to enquire if I still have a valid esta for entry into USA feb 2020

Answer (score 20):

An ESTA is not a physical object, it is an electronic record.
From the [ESTA FAQ](https://esta.cbp.dhs.gov/faq?lang=en):

> **Do I need to bring a printout or digital copy of my travel authorization to the airport?**
>
> No. DHS will be able to communicate a traveler's ESTA status to the carriers. However, DHS recommends that travelers print out the travel authorization application response in order to maintain a record of their traveler authorization application number and to have confirmation of their ESTA status.
>
> U.S. regulation does NOT require a Visa Waiver Program (VWP) traveler to present a printed copy of the ESTA authorization page in order to travel. However, it is recommended that you print a copy for your records. If you did not receive or cannot locate your application number, you may retrieve the application through the ESTA website by entering your passport number, country of citizenship, passport issuance date, passport expiration date, and date of birth.

You can confirm your ESTA status [here](https://esta.cbp.dhs.gov/), by clicking *CHECK ESTA STATUS* in the menu bar. You can then print another copy of the confirmation of your status, if you wish.

Comment: And anyone who is unable to let go of the idea that they need a physical copy can print another copy from the website, which will be just as valid as the lost copy.  Anyway, its a good idea to have a copy even though it should not be necessary.

Comment: When we tried to check in for a flight from Auckland to LAX the American Airlines staff required us to show proof of ESTA.  They wouldn't let anyone check-in without seeing it (or Visa etc.).  We hadn't printed anything off (as the ESTA website said we didn't need to) and argued that point, but still we had to pull out the laptop, connect to the internet, and show the ESTA details there before they'd let us proceed.  Now we print everything, even if it says we don't need to.

Comment: @MJeffryes I have moved the "Check ESTA" link to the top to make it more obvious

Comment: @Midavalo indeed.  That's why I wrote "it's a good idea to have a copy even though it should not be necessary."  Maybe their systems were down, though, because they normally can't let anyone board without sending the passport number to the US government and getting a message back that authorizes boarding.  Printed confirmation of ESTA is not necessary for that process.

Comment: Yeah I've found that some airlines require a paper printout (presumably to avoid wasting space in the queues by people who, it turns out, don't actually have an ESTA). I imagine saying "yes I have an ESTA but I lost my printout, sorry" should be a trivial way to get past that, but Midavalo's experience shows that may not be the case. Besides, it's trivial to go online at home, log into your account, and print out a new copy, so... just do that.